# Grails Interactive mode getting "Resource temporarily unavailable" error on Linux

Tags: grails

We using Grails 2.4.5 on a project, and normally running interactive mode on our Linux machines work. I'm not sure what changed, we did not alter any java or grails configs.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error reading input: Resource temporarily unavailable
    at grails.build.logging.GrailsConsole.readLine(GrailsConsole.java:793)
    at grails.build.logging.GrailsConsole.showPrompt(GrailsConsole.java:779)
    at grails.build.logging.GrailsConsole.showPrompt(GrailsConsole.java:805)
    at grails.build.logging.GrailsConsole$showPrompt$1.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.interactive.InteractiveMode.showPrompt(InteractiveMode.groovy:50)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.interactive.InteractiveMode$showPrompt.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:137)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.interactive.InteractiveMode.run(InteractiveMode.groovy:114)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.main(GrailsScriptRunner.java:216)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.rootLoader(GrailsStarter.java:236)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.main(GrailsStarter.java:264)
| Error Interactive mode exited with error: Error reading input: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Tried creating a new project and has the same error there too.

What's causing this? Do you see clues in the stack trace on why?

Comment: I'm seeing the same behavior in a Grails 2.5.6 project... just started seeing it yesterday.  Same stacktrace hierarchy.  Running Grails provided by sdkman on Ubuntu.